# VisualVM cant open local VM for profiling

Tags: java, visualvm

I am trying to open a local java app for profiling with VisualVM but it has suddenly stopped working since I last used it a week ago, I can see the programs in the applications box but if I try to open my program launched from the cmd line or any other java program like eclipse it will just hang with the status bar saying opening. If it try to select another VM to open while it is trying to open my own app, visualVM will lock up.

Note that I can open and profile the visualVM JVM but not any other,

I haven't changed any settings other than performing general OS updates including the kernel. I have made sure my /tmp/hsperfdata_myusername is accessable and I can see file numbers matching the process pid created in the folder when I launch visual VM, eclipse or my own java program from the command line. I tried launching my own program and visualvm as root and trying it but it made no difference.  I have deleted my .visualvm folder to clear any issues but it did't work and the log file for visualvm does not mention any errors.

I'm runnning fedora 19 with java 7_u45-b18.

when I launch visual vm a port is opened  TCP localhost6.localdomain6:35138 (LISTEN)

If I open my own app or eclipse and leave it for 10 minuites it will finally connect (used to be instantly ), however CPU profiling and GC commands are disabled which is what I want.

I know you need to specify JMX ports for remote connections but this is all local so I can't see why it has suddenly gone tits up!

Any Help would be most welcome.

Comment: Note: I managed to get it working buy adding the following JVM parameter:-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost although it does not explain why it worked before without it, before I had my issues. Even with the parameter it does not work if I launch my app from eclipse in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me, too! In my case it never worked (hang while opening), both the downloaded and the one provided with the JDK. With this option it could profile. [EDIT]: No, it does not work, it worked only for profiling itself, i.e. VisualVM…

Comment: using the VM flag -XX:+StartAttachListener may also help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM Arguments and add below argument if you want to profile local process:
**-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost**

Answer (score 0):

One way to investigate your problem is to get the log of JVisualVM by passing JVM option to command jvisualvm

https://hoangx281283.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/getting-log-of-jvisualvm/